# Does Apache Cassandra support schema free?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, nosql

We can do Schema free with Document-based database such as MongoDB or CouchDB.

Apache Cassandra is not document-based. It is Wide Column based.

My question is does Apache Cassandra support Scheme free? Or support some kind of design is for Scheme free?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it does not. At least definitely not in the way of MongoDB/CouchDB. You kind of answered your own question when you said "Cassandra is Wide Column" based.

You might find this an interesting read. http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/the-myth-of-schema-less/